# Does ChronicleWire support optional fields in entities?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-wire

I am experimenting with ChronicleWire. As described in [features](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Wire#features) optional fields are supported out of the box.

I just created a simple self-describing entity with one optional (nullable) field:

```
public class Foo extends SelfDescribingMarshallable {

  private String name;
  private Baz baz;
}
```

where `baz` might or might not be null and implements/extends Marshallable.

When I try to put entity to ChronicleMap I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.BytesMarshaller$BytesMarshallableFieldAccess.getValue(BytesMarshaller.java:211)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.BytesMarshaller$FieldAccess.write(BytesMarshaller.java:152)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.BytesMarshaller.writeMarshallable(BytesMarshaller.java:70)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.BytesUtil.writeMarshallable(BytesUtil.java:295)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.BytesMarshallable.writeMarshallable(BytesMarshallable.java:48)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.BytesMarshaller$BytesMarshallableFieldAccess.getValue(BytesMarshaller.java:211)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.BytesMarshaller$FieldAccess.write(BytesMarshaller.java:152)
```

When I tried to use java optional instead and my entity changed to:

```
    public class Foo extends SelfDescribingMarshallable {

      private String name;
      private Optional<Baz> baz = Optional.empty();
    }
```

then another error raised:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: type=class java.util.Optional is unsupported, it must either be of type Marshallable, String or AutoBoxed primitive Object
    at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.ValueOut.object(ValueOut.java:682)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.ValueOut.untypedObject(ValueOut.java:795)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.ValueOut.object(ValueOut.java:519)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.WireMarshaller$ObjectFieldAccess.getValue(WireMarshaller.java:669)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.WireMarshaller$FieldAccess.write(WireMarshaller.java:518)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.WireMarshaller.writeMarshallable(WireMarshaller.java:199)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.Marshallable.writeMarshallable(Marshallable.java:132)
```

I did not give up and tried to implement my own optional. Here it's:

```
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
@NoArgsConstructor(staticName = "empty")
public class OptionalValue<T extends Marshallable> implements Marshallable {

    @Nullable
    private T value;

    @Override
    public void readMarshallable(@NotNull WireIn wire) throws IORuntimeException {
        var val = wire.read("value");
        if (!val.isNull()) {
            val.marshallable(value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void writeMarshallable(@NotNull WireOut wire) {
        if (value == null) {
            wire.write("value").nu11();
        } else {
            wire.write("value").marshallable(value);
        }
    }

    boolean isEmpty() { return value == null; }

    T get() { return value; }
}
```

In this case, I saw another error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException

    at net.openhft.chronicle.core.util.ObjectUtils.asCCE(ObjectUtils.java:294)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.core.util.ObjectUtils$ConversionFunction.apply(ObjectUtils.java:624)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.core.util.ObjectUtils$ConversionFunction.apply(ObjectUtils.java:592)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.core.ClassLocal.computeValue(ClassLocal.java:54)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromHashMap(ClassValue.java:226)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromBackup(ClassValue.java:208)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.get(ClassValue.java:114)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.core.util.ObjectUtils.convertTo0(ObjectUtils.java:257)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.redacted.entity.OptionalValue.<init>(java.lang.String)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.redacted.entity.OptionalValue.<init>(java.lang.String)

    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.core.util.ObjectUtils$ConversionFunction.apply(ObjectUtils.java:620)
```

So does anybody know how to fix or use it properly?
ChronicleWire 2.22ae6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `SelfDescribingMarshallable` is `BytesMarsahallable`, Map prefers to use this lower level serialization. However, because it is so low level, it doesn't support `null` values.

You can tell the builder to use `Marshallable` by setting the `valueMarshaller`

```
.valueMarshaller(new MarshallableReaderWriter<>(Foo.class))
```